# Add URL for more than 30 days under Internet Explorer mode pages under Edge Browser with users signed in /non local mode

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

As we know new Edge versions are coming with IE mode option where we can add legacy application URL to make it run with IE Mode option. However, this option is available with 30 days limitation & after this expiry we again have to add that URL to continue.

Anyone knows option to modify this 30 days expire or is it possible by using any script / by configuring any policies for browser with users signed in to edge?

If I am not wrong there is a a script that is configuring for local profile

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure group policies to set IE mode sites. It won't have time restriction. You can refer to [Configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies) about how to configure Edge IE mode via GPO. The steps are like below:

1. [Enable Internet Explorer integration using Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#enable-internet-explorer-integration-using-group-policy)
2. [Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy)

For how to create the Enterprise Mode Site List, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/add-multiple-sites-to-enterprise-mode-site-list-using-the-version-2-schema-and-enterprise-mode-tool).

Comment: Is there like a GPO settings to set to prevent users from signing in to Microsoft Edge ?

Comment: You can set this policy [BrowserSignin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#browsersignin) to **Disable** to disable browser sign-in.

Comment: Thank you Yu Zhou . Can i check do i have to download the edge policy template to configure ? Do you have a photo of where can i see the setting ? if yes can you attach a photo here thanks

Comment: You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge) about how to download and configure Edge policy template. Screenshot of policy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh6uY.png.

Comment: Thank you @yu zhou - I just realsie the GPO  only work with the latest version of Edge 190 and above . - But thank you i had tried to use reg edit and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Use regedit to disable user from adding profile

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/162032-how-enable-disable-force-sign-microsoft-edge-chromium.html

[Sucess run of disabled users to sign into edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya40D.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).